# How can I remove adhesive bandaging from my dog without hurting her?

Tags: dogs, wound-care, pain

My dog recently had surgery and they covered the wound with a bandage that had an adhesive border around the wound site.

We followed the instructions of the vet and when it came to removing the bandage it was so sticky it was pulling at her skin and making her yelp. It was painful. We were scared to continue removing it and wanted to know of something we could use to perhaps dissolve the stickiness.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To remove bandages you can use peanut oil or other types of vegetable oil.

The best oil to use is peanut oil and you simply moisten the bandage by adding the oil a few minutes before you want to remove the bandage.

If you are to replace a bandage using oil is a bit problematic as it makes it hard to get the new bandage to stick to the skin/fur.

I get peanut oil at the pharmacy as this is the cleanest and best type one can get.

Comment: thanks for this. Have you heard of using methylated spirits to remove bandages?

Comment: @YvetteColomb i have but in my experience methyl alcohol do evaporate too quickly to be helpfull in removing bandages and it does dry out the skin of your pet,peanut oil does not evaporate and it does protect the skin of your pet against drying out and it is seen as safe to use on the skin of most animals.and it is safe to eat i do not think spirits are safe to consume for our pets :)

Comment: Interestingly the vet used methylated spirits on it today. I thought that may be good if you need to put another dressing on and the peanut oil if you don't. Thoughts?

Comment: @YvetteColomb if one have to put on a new dressing right away methylated spirits might be better to use than oil,i am not sure about how methylated spirit might feel if there is an open wound but i think it might be slightly uncomfortable ;)

Comment: oh I'm sure they wouldn't put it on the open wound, just on the adhesive on the bandage that sits around the wound